# What is a material that attracts radio waves, or how can I make one at home?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

When I search this up, all the results are about electromagnetic shielding. What can I do if I want to pull in radio waves?

Comment: You need an *antenna.*

Comment: Well, an antenna can absorb radio waves, but how can I _attract_ it?

Comment: Use a reflector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no materials that attract radio waves or any other EM waves.  You can focus them by using an antenna. You'll increase the collection area and focus it to a point. This is not a radio waver attracter though.

Answer (score 0):

Radio waves, like all waves, can not be attracted at a distance. They can; however, be focused. Light can be focused with a lens, waves incident on a beach are focused or diverge due to the contours of the sand bed underneath, and radio waves can be focused due to atmospheric temperature and pressure gradients.

They can also be reflected. Satellite dishes e.g. make use of this to reflectively focus waves incident on the reflector area to a point.

For good reception, you want a good signal to noise ratio. I.e. IF you could attract waves, what good would it do you if you also attracted noise in the same proportion. Non-dish antennas DO NOT focus light in reception, but a phased array of them (eg a Yagi) can be used to selectively capture signal and noise from a particular direction. If you know where your signal is coming from then you can point your array in that direction and get better quality. The same amount of signal waves are incident on your antenna but as you get less noise you do better.